# Retriving the 'match' patterns from the column of a dataframe and append in list

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I want to retrieve the values of order numbers and store it in a list. But the problem is I am able to fetch one not the other

```
ID                        Order
test@xyz.com      1-1155945200890<<<<able to fetch this
test1@xyz.com     Hi how are you? 1-1155945200890<<<not able to fetch
```

By using below I am able to retrive the values to those column which do not have the junk data with it like that of just `'1-1155945200890' but not from 'Hi how are you? 1-1155945200890'`

To define feedback:

```
for user in users:
    intent_name=data_to_analyse2.loc[data_to_analyse2['ID'] ==  user]
    intent_list=list(intent_name['INTENTNAME'])
    feedback=list(intent_name['Input'])
```

to fetch the match pattern:

```
pattern=re.compile("1[\-][\d]{2,15}")
pattern_list=list(filter(pattern.match, feedback))
```

How can I get all the values to the matching expression even if it has junk data associated with it

Comment: Try `df.Order.str.extract(r'(1[\-][\d]{2,15})')`.

Comment: @ResidentSleeper Would require a solution from regex point of view as there are multiple patterns to be extracted and all those extracted patterns are to be put in a list